# Can't take photo from camera only in Lenovo A750

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I try take photo from camera this way:

```
private void photo() {

        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
            String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getName() + File.separatorChar + "app/photo/";    
            mPushFilePath = directory + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            File imageFile = new File(mPushFilePath);
            Uri mImageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    mImageFileUri);    
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_RESULT);
        }    
    }
```

And I take picture in method `onActivityResult` from path `mPushFilePath` 
In all devices this code working perfectly. But in **Lenovo A750**, when I try get picture, button **v** (or **ok**) doesn't work. Please, help me to fix this.

Comment: Button v? Is this the button to start the onClickActivity... or the "Okay" button that shows up after you've captured a photo in the camera application?

Comment: This is the button that shows up after captured a photo in the camera application

Comment: This would be a Lenovo specific issue, and you may need to contact them about getting it resolved. The only issue with that, is that it's generally extremely difficult to get ahold of someone who is developing for them... and most tech support people read from a support manual. Try contacting Lenovo representatives on Google+ and see if they can get you good contact information.

Comment: I can't contact with Lenovo representatives. Anybody, have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way: When need to call the camera, if the device Lenovo, I call the custom camera that made ​​myself. If not, everything is as it used to.